# Meaning of default names for threads in Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat7

I was looking at my log4j2 log file and noticing the names of the threads in Apache Tomcat (v7.0.42):

```
2013-08-26 20:48:05,858 INFO c.k.s.u.VelocitySearchBase [http-bio-443-exec-8] Query found
```

And the name of the thread `http-bio-443-exec-8` seems to make some sense except the `bio` part. Does anyone know what `bio` signifies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I think I found the answer. I see reference to connector types on [this page](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html) where they are called BIO, NIO and AJP.... probably `bio` refers to blocking io. If it had been using new io and it said `nio`, I probably would never have had to ask, but bio made me think biology not input/output :).